# Local site not working

Tags: 7, acquia-dev-desktop

I've pulled down a site using dev desktop but none of the styles are working. I think it's a problem with the settings file.

There are multiple sites on this environment. In Dev Desktop, I chose to clone an environment, specified a specific site, and cloned it locally. I am able to view the site and images but the stylesheets are loading. I also can't access the admin area. Drush seems to work fine.

The only error I'm seeing is "The file could not be created." In the past I've had to create a settings.local.php file but that doesn't seem to be working, either.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you make title more meaningful?

Comment: Can you share a version of your settings file that may give some insight?

Answer (score 0):

The message `The file could not be created` indicates a permissions issue to me. Make sure that the webserver has the ability to create files in all the places in needs.